# Are game review questions appropriate for BCG?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

A game review would be highly subjective, however, it would also be useful for gathering thoughts on a game that the OP or readers may not come up with on their own. They could be useful community questions.

Comment: Exactly what sort of question do you mean? Do you mean, a request for a review, as in "Are there any reviews for [Game X]"? It would be good to include such an example question in your question, or maybe link to a question on the site if you have seen one.

Comment: @Erik, I haven't seen one yet. Basically, a request for opinions and insight (such as a particular angle, as per @Brian) on a game. I understand the need for questions to be directed at some particular problem, like @Brian said in an answer below. However, with general reviews on other sites, I don't think they can accomplish what you could here on an SE site. With votes, you can weed out reviews and also keep context of comments with an answer (without having to read an entire forum topic like you would on BoardGameGeek).

Answer (score 10):

If you're just soliciting reviews for Game X with no additional information provided, that's probably not a good use of the site. BoardGameGeek already has a "reviews" section for each game, as well as ratings and comments that many people write for many games, and there are lots of other places that people can find game reviews; Googling for "[Game X] review" will usually find them.

If you want a review from a particular angle that you haven't seen covered before, that's acceptable. For instance, if you ask "[Game X] says ages 7 and up. My 10 year old son has [such and such mental handicap]. Will this game be appropriate for him?" or "[Game X] appears popular among hardcore gamers; how does it play in a family setting, with a few precocious children?", then those are soliciting reviews from a specific angle that may not be adequately addressed by existing reviews.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is not the question but the poorness of the question.